# Make -132,680 from these operations

Tags: mathematics, computer-puzzle

Make the result $-132,680$ using these operations and numbers:

**Numbers** (cannot be used more than once, but not all need to be used):

> $2,4,6,8,9,10,11,12,23,27$

**Operations** (**all operations have to be used once and once only**):

> - $\Box + \Box$
> - $\Box - \Box$
> - $\Box \times \Box$
> - $\Box \div \Box$
> - $\Box^{\Box}$
> - $\log_{10}{\Box}$
> - $\sqrt[2]{\Box}$
> - $\Box !$

Hints:

> The ! operation needs to be done first

Comment: Can you clarify whether the log and root functions are unary or binary and, if unary, what base the former has?

Comment: @msh210 Base 10

Comment: @msh210 Unary, the root has a base of 2 (square-root) of a single number

Comment: How can there be 10 numbers but only 5 binary operators? Is there implicit multiplication/division or concatenation of numbers?

Comment: @eyl327 I should make it clear all numbers do not need to be used

Comment: @Daniil I see, thanks.

Comment: For future reference, @Danlil: Try putting the hints in spoiler blocks (use `>!`) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I've found:

> $$ \frac{6! + \log\left(10\right) - 27 ^ 4}{\sqrt{2 \times 8}} = -132680 $$

Comment: Well done, that's correct

Answer (score 8):

Okay here's one way to do it (each operation used once).

> $$-132680 = \left(\frac{6}{\log(\sqrt{10})} \times (8^2 + 4) \right) - !9$$ where $!9$ is the [subfactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html) of $9$ ($!9 = 133496$)

Comment: Not my intended method but well done anyway

Comment: Ah rot13(Fhosnpgbevny!) That's really neat. I didn't expect that interpretation. +1